# Nice tutorial(s) for Gmail and web for old person

Tags: gmail

My mom just got a laptop. She's 82 and speaks French and English.
Do you know any nice and easy tutorials for Gmail, the web...?
She's been using Word a few years so she's not totally lost, but the web side of things is really new for her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has a video tutorial site, [TeachParentsTech.org](http://www.teachparentstech.org/), with a bunch of videos by Googlers explaining common computer activities.